# iOS 7.1 beta 4 – Safari bug fixed?

Tags: ios7, crash, mobile-safari

Does anyone know or did anyone experience, if the latest beta from iOS 7.1 (beta 4) fixes the annoying crashes of Safari App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is YES! they've fixed the bug!